# Use R to aggregate and return the mean based on "if" criteria

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, aggregate

I want to use the `aggregate` function to create a table that has the columns `date` (structured as a date) and `time.to.complete` (structured as difftime), where time is a calculated as a mean. The `time.to.complete` data has negative values. I want to exclude all negative values when I calculate my mean.

Currently, my aggregate function looks like:

```
mean.table<-aggregate(data$time.to.complete, list(data$date), mean)
```

I can calculate the overall mean of time.to.complete without the negative values with:

```
average<-with(data, mean(data$time.to.complete[time.to.complete>0]))
```

However, I cannot figure out how to combine the two functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(MeanbyDate = mean(time.to.complete),
      MeanOveralltime = mean(data$time.to.complete[data$time.to.complete > 0])), by = date]
```

If we want to have the group by for `> 0`

```
setDT(data)[, .(MeanbyDate = mean(time.to.complete),
      MeanGreaterthan0 = mean(time.to.complete[time.to.complete > 0])), by = date]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.